# Reference request for texts that treat classical mechanics in a mathematical manner

Tags: reference-request, classical-mechanics

I am looking for books and papers that treat the physics theory of classical mechanics in a rigorous, mathematical manner. I would love to read such a text. Are there even such texts out there? I have already read physics books on classical mechanics, I am now looking for a rigorous mathematical text on it.

Comment: Spivak has a text. See also Abraham and Marsden. There’s also Arnold’s text. There are several other textbooks which treat topics like differential geometry and parts of classical mechanics. It all depends on what you’re looking for.

Comment: I second on [Arnold](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Classical-Mechanics-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387968903/ref=asc_df_0387968903?tag=bngsmtphsnus-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=80608063550946&hvnetw=s&hvqmt=e&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=&hvtargid=pla-4584207589762542&psc=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* is the standard in this regard.